# Square Every Digit

Tags: python

anyone could possibly help out why i've got such an error?

```py
    def square_digits(num):
        result = [] 
        for x in num:
            result.append(x**2)
            return result
        pass
```

`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you sending `square_digits`? Is it possible you're sending an `int`?

Comment: You can't iterate over the digits of a number.

Comment: Can you provide some context? Maybe your ```num``` is not a list?

Comment: Why do you have a return there in the loop, why do you have a pass after the loop, you cannot just iterate a number!?

Comment: Integer isnt a list. You need to separate out the digits mathematically

Comment: % by 10 gives you a digit then you go // 10 to remove it, and you do this until you reach your desired one.  Duplicate, flagging.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.
Convert the number to list of strings (digits of number) and iterate through this list.

Convert back to int when performing the square calculation (or convert to float if you are using non-int numbers)

```
    def square_digits(num):
        result = []
        nums = list(str(num))
        for x in nums:
            result.append(int(x)**2)
        return result
```